# What is wrong with my bone rig and what settings have I messed up?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

[image: imageN]

I've created movement before with a simpler bone rig and since then have weight painted the entire model to red.

Whenever I go into pose mode and try to move anything, nothing happens, I simply can't get any movement.

Is there an armature setting I could be missing?

Here is my blender file.

http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=49231

Comment: The link provided does not allow to download the file here...

Comment: it's a little slow but it worked fine for me

Comment: oh it was mostly painted black.. but still won't move

Comment: Please aviod using Pasteall.org  to upload files. Links expire on that site.  Use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ instead for a permanent link

Answer (score 1):

Nothing moves because the "manipulate center points" is checked:

[image]

Comment: can you move one of his extremities?

Comment: okay I figured it out I had to select my armature that was made as a parent file, as an armature of the orginal object

Comment: well now I can't do it again, but I think I check bone envelope, can't find the setting now

Comment: yep that was it in create copy check bone envelope

Comment: main model, maintenance tab, armature, add created bone structure, check bone envelope.

Comment: actually it's painted all black except his head probably why there's so much distortion

Comment: facebook.com/gettingnifty